# PostgreSQL user login

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have created a new user in postgresql database,

```
create user newusr with password 'password';
postgres=# alter user newusr with superuser;
```

but I cant log in with the name of this user...

```
sudo -u newusr psql
```

Why and how can I change this?
I am on ubuntu

Comment: What about `psql -U newusr`?

Comment: Have you tried to specify "host"?
 -h 127.0.0.1
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: `sudo -u newusr` switches to a different **Linux** user, it does not log you into the database. There is no need to use `sudo` at all. Just use `psql -u newusr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres typically maintains a completely separate list of users to Ubuntu.  To create a linux user you'd typically use a command such as `useradd`

The `CREATE USER` command you issued created a new user for the database.   This will mean that you can (depending on the pg_hba.conf settings) use the username newusr and password "password" to connect to the postgres database.

Typically using a command such as:

```
psql -U newusr
```

The sudo command you used changes the operating system user.  In this particular case, I'm assuming that its erroring with a messages like:

```
sudo: unknown user: newusr
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

This is because `newusr` only exists in the database.